# what word means Sadness and concern?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to write a story, but I cannot, for the life of me, think of the proper word to describe this. I don't want to use pity, since it seems too demeaning of a word, and I can't think of anything else. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Sympathy?  Empathy?  Compassion? Condolence? Understanding?

Answer (score 1):

*[Sympathy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sympathy)* is a fairly good fit:

> : the feeling that you care about and are sorry about someone else's trouble, grief, misfortune, etc. : a sympathetic feeling

Answer (score 0):

compassion? resonance? empathy?

Comment: Answers should be based on some reliable references and not just  suggestions.